# Minimum singular value of product of two matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, svd, singular-values

Let $\bf A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix and $\bf B$ be a $n \times k$ matrix. Let $\sigma_{\min} ({\bf M})$ denote the minimum singular value of matrix $\bf M$. Does the following hold?

$$\sigma_{\min} ({\bf AB}) \geq \sigma_{\min} ({\bf A}) \, \sigma_{\min} ({\bf B})$$

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value#Singular_values_of_AB) (and the references).

Comment: Thank you so much!